# Twitter has a rate limit of 180 calls every 15 minutes

Tags: python, json, twitter

Python struggling to read many JSON files?

I'm writing a short script to check for which 5 letter twitter handles are available, basically 5 for loops and then using Twitter API to check if it is available.

In the middle for loop I have two lines:

```
response = requests.get("https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=" + user)
print user, str(response.json()["valid"])
```

It ran for a little bit and at some point decided it couldn't read JSON files anymore, and now when I try running it it stops immediately with the same error:

```
  File "check.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "check.py", line 16, in main
    print user, str(response.json()["valid"])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 886, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The only logical answer that comes to my mind is that my computer can't handle so many JSON requests but I was wondering if anyone knew any way to get around this.

Comment: Check if there a hit limit to twitter API. It's possible that after certain hits, it refuses the connection.

Comment: This is not your computer. You should print request before doing it and show us the last one which is failling.

Comment: Did you check that the URL where it croaked is a valid Twitter URL?

Comment: @Clément I said it was failing immediately

Comment: turns out twitter has a rate limit

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out after many minutes of confusion..

Twitter has a rate limit of 180 calls every 15 minutes.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting